# How to apply policy tags with dataform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, etl, dataform

I'm trying to use Dataform(GCP) to apply PolicyTags, it runs successfully, but PolicyTag is not applied to the specified column.

This is an example that is on the Dataform website, and it doesn't work either.

```
config {
  type: "table",
  columns: {
    column1: {
      description: "Some description",
      bigqueryPolicyTags: ["projects/dataform-integration-tests/locations/us/taxonomies/800183280162998443/policyTags/494923997126550963"]
    }
  }
}

select "test" as column1
```

I've already tried to check the user's grants, and it's with the BigQuery Admin and DataplexAdmin grants.

Has anyone had the same problem and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really was a bug, and Google has already fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).